# PostgreSQL 9.3: Update table without using if condition

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have the following table with two columns namely FirstName and Num as shown as below:

**Table**: Test

```
CREATE TABLE Test
(
FirstName VARCHAR(10),
Num int
);
```

**Insertion**:

```
INSERT INTO Test VALUES('b',1);
INSERT INTO Test VALUES('ba',2);
INSERT INTO Test VALUES('bac',3);
```

**Note**: Now I want to update the FirstName in the table by using the function. The table should be
only get updated if I pass some value of firstName to function, else if I pass empty string or null
value then it should not get updated means that it should hold its old value only. **And I don't want
to use IF Condition for that**.

## My Try:

**Function**: fun_test

```
create or replace function fun_test(p_FirstName varchar(50),p_num int)
RETURNS BOOLEAN
AS
$boday$
BEGIN

Update Test
set    FirstName = COALESCE(p_FirstName,FirstName) 
WHERE Num = p_num;

RETURN FOUND;

END;
$boday$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

**Calling Function**:

**Condition 1**: The following calling function should not update the old values of FirstName.

```
SELECT * from fun_test('',3);
```

**Condition 2**: The following calling function should update the old values of FirstName.

```
SELECT * from fun_test('xyz',3);
```

Comment: Sounds like a home work assignment. When you refere the coalsece doc, you will find that it returns the first non null element.

Comment: `coalesce()` checks for `null` values and an empty string (`''`) is not a `null` value. Also: you should call the function like this: `select fun_test(...)`. Because it does not return a resultset, it should not be put into the `from` clause.